# PHP using the select tag

Tags: php, function, select

I would like help with my homework.
I need to use a select menu and then put the selection of the select tag into a function. Now when I tried doing this I get an undefined error (Which is weird since I did define it) I have tried to do the full if system. But I soon gave up because it was just way to much work, while there is probbaly a better way of doing this.
Here is my code:

```
<form action=<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>>
            Vertrek:
            <select name="vertrek">
                <option value="amsterdam">Amsterdam</option>
                <option value="utrecht">Utrecht</option>
                <option value="denhaag">Den Haag</option>
                <option value="rotterdam">Rotterdam</option>
            </select>
            Aankomst:
            <select name="aankomst">
                <option value="amsterdam2">Amsterdam</option>
                <option value="utrecht2">Utrecht</option>
                <option value="denhaag2">Den Haag</option>
                <option value="rotterdam2">Rotterdam</option>
            </select>
            <br/><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Berekenen">
            <p>------</p>
            De berekende reiskosten zijn:
            <?php 
                reiskosten(isset($_POST['vertrek']), isset($_POST['aankomst']));            
            ?> Euros's
```

And the "reiskosten" function:

```
<?php
            function reiskosten($vertrek, $bestemming)
            {
                $reiskosten = array();
                $reiskosten[1] = array();
                $reiskosten[2] = array();
                $reiskosten[3] = array();
                $reiskosten[4] = array();

                //Amsterdam naar iets
                $reiskosten[1][1] = 0;
                $reiskosten[1][2] = 30;
                $reiskosten[1][3] = 60;
                $reiskosten[1][4] = 90;

                //Utrecht naar iets
                $reiskosten[2][1] = 30;
                $reiskosten[2][2] = 0;
                $reiskosten[2][3] = 40;
                $reiskosten[2][4] = 20;

                //Den Haag naar iets
                $reiskosten[3][1] = 60;
                $reiskosten[3][2] = 40;
                $reiskosten[3][3] = 0;
                $reiskosten[3][4] = 10;

                //Rotterdam naar iets
                $reiskosten[4][1] = 90;
                $reiskosten[4][2] = 20;
                $reiskosten[4][3] = 10;
                $reiskosten[4][4] = 0;

                echo($reiskosten[$vertrek][$bestemming] . " Euro's ");
            }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you'll want to fix is that you're calling your reiskosten() function with the wrong arguments. What you mean to do is pass form values to that function, but if you look carefully, you'll see that you're passing the return values of the isset() function, each of which is going to be a boolean (TRUE/FALSE) value, not the value from the form element itself.  That said, once you fix that, you'll realize that even the value of the form element is not quite what you'll want either. At that point you'll either adjust what the value="" attributes contain, or re-evaluate the way you're indexing things on the back end. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for this answer, i shall look further into this. Though its weird, my book said i had to do it this way. My book is completely useless..

Comment: I accepted this answer because it came the closest to what i need. eventually this line fixed it (thanks to itachi too for the GET tip, i gave you an upvote for that) reiskosten($_GET['vertrek'], $_GET['aankomst']);

Answer (score 1):

Your  values are strings no integers.
`$reiskosten[$vertrek][$bestemming]` is not defined since its 
ie. `$reiskosten['rotterdam']['rotterdam2']` is not defined.
You might want to change your array keys to strings or the option value to integers.

Answer (score 1):

your form is `GET`. You are checking for  `POST` variables.

Comment: @mightyuhu you are mistaken, GET is the default.

Comment: GET did fix it. Yet i do got a problem with the function, but it seems vaporbook has answered that.

Answer (score 1):

Your form should be:

```
<form action=<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>>
        Vertrek:
        <select name="vertrek">
            <option value="1">Amsterdam</option>
            <option value="2">Utrecht</option>
            <option value="3">Den Haag</option>
            <option value="4">Rotterdam</option>
        </select>
        Aankomst:
        <select name="aankomst">
            <option value="1">Amsterdam</option>
            <option value="2">Utrecht</option>
            <option value="3">Den Haag</option>
            <option value="4">Rotterdam</option>
        </select>
        <br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Berekenen">
        <p>------</p>
        De berekende reiskosten zijn:
        <?php 
            $reiskosten = reiskosten($_POST['vertrek'], $_POST['aankomst']);
            echo $reiskosten . "Euros's";
        ?>
```

1. option values should (in this instance) be integers.
2. remove isset() as this only checks if they are set and does not actually return their values.
3. Create a new variable ($reiskosten) which will be the returned result of the function, and echo it out.

Your PHP should be:

```
<?php
        function reiskosten($vertrek, $bestemming)
        {
            $reiskosten = array();
            $reiskosten[1] = array();
            $reiskosten[2] = array();
            $reiskosten[3] = array();
            $reiskosten[4] = array();

            //Amsterdam naar iets
            $reiskosten[1][1] = 0;
            $reiskosten[1][2] = 30;
            $reiskosten[1][3] = 60;
            $reiskosten[1][4] = 90;

            //Utrecht naar iets
            $reiskosten[2][1] = 30;
            $reiskosten[2][2] = 0;
            $reiskosten[2][3] = 40;
            $reiskosten[2][4] = 20;

            //Den Haag naar iets
            $reiskosten[3][1] = 60;
            $reiskosten[3][2] = 40;
            $reiskosten[3][3] = 0;
            $reiskosten[3][4] = 10;

            //Rotterdam naar iets
            $reiskosten[4][1] = 90;
            $reiskosten[4][2] = 20;
            $reiskosten[4][3] = 10;
            $reiskosten[4][4] = 0;

            $return = $reiskosten[$vertrek][$bestemming];

            return $return;
        }
    ?>
```

No need to echo out here, just return the value.

Comment: won't downvote but add `method="POST"` in the form attribute.

Answer (score 1):

The `isset()` function returns `true` or `false`, so the following line is incorrect since you appear to want to send the values through:

```
reiskosten(isset($_POST['vertrek']), isset($_POST['aankomst']));
```

Change it to:

```
if( isset($_POST['vertrek']) && isset($_POST['aankomst']) ) {
  reiskosten($_POST['vertrek'], $_POST['aankomst']);
}
```

Also, the values for `vertrek` and `aankomst` will be whatever the `value` field in the HTML `option` is, so it will be a name, not a number.

You can address it by using associative arrays like:

```
$reiskosten = array();
$reiskosten['amsterdam'] = array();
$reiskosten['utrecht'] = array();
$reiskosten['denhaag'] = array();
$reiskosten['rotterdam'] = array();
```

And the same for the sub-array definitions where you set the prices.